# how to prevent action overriding from overriding the editable onRowAdd button in material-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I want to to be able to add new data to my table and also have an action button. I need to override the action field and use a button because I want it to open a material UI menu. However, when overriding it also replaces the add button that comes with the Edittable onRowAdd feature. You can replicate the issue by pasting the below code in the 'Action overidding example' code window here: 
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding

You can see the add button here in 'Editable Example':
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable

```
class ActionOverriding extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MaterialTable
          editable={{
        onRowAdd: newData =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    {}
                    resolve();
                }, 1000);}),}}
        title="Action Overriding Preview"
        options={{
            export:true,
        }}
        columns={[
          { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        ]}
        data={[{ name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },]}
        actions={[{
            icon: 'save',
            tooltip: 'Save User',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You saved " + rowData.name)
          }]} 
        components={{
          Action: props => (
            <Button onClick={(event) => props.action.onClick(event, props.data)} color="primary" variant="contained" style={{textTransform: 'none'}} size="small">My Button</Button>
),}}/>)}}
```